# elasticsearch: which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to start elasticsearch on gcp, however, I am facing the below error.

```
Nov 06 06:29:07 poc-02 systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Nov 06 06:29:07 poc-02 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Nov 06 06:29:07 poc-02 elasticsearch[8939]: which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

However, i have java present in path `/usr/bin`. Any hint?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you trying to start? What version of java is installed?

Comment: @YuriTceretian: Elasticsearch latest verison 5.6.3 and java 1.8.0